# Transfer Access Code into Oracle Syntax (Power Query)

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, powerquery

I am just woorking on to transfer a Access Query into Power Query (Excel).
I think there are some challenges regarding the terms/ wording.
Its a Oracle DB.

The original code looks like this one:

```
SELECT 
    POOLK.DATA.DOC, 
    Val(Min(Right([PNR],5))) AS Value, 
    POOLK.DATA.RE, 
    POOLK.DATA.ST INTO [tValue]
FROM 
    POOLK.DATA
GROUP BY 
    POOLK.DATA.DOC, 
    POOLK.DATA.RE, 
    POOLK.DATA.ST
HAVING (((POOLK.DATA.DOC)>25000) AND ((POOLK.DATA.RE)="B9"))
ORDER BY POOLK.DATA.DOC DESC
```

This is my approach since now:

```
SELECT
    LTRIM((SUBSTR(POOLK.DATA."PNR", -5)), '0') AS Value,
    POOLK.DATA.DOC,
    POOLK.DATA.RE,
    POOLK.DATA.ST
FROM 
    POOLK.DATA
WHERE   
    POOLK.DATA.DOC >25000
      AND 
    POOLK.DATA.RE ='B9'
```

I get failures with the HAVING and GROUP BY functions.
I think where presents other value, right?

Have someone ideas?

Best Regards

Comment: Your second query is not an aggregate query like first version.

Comment: since you don't show your oracle (as opposed to your Access) code with any HAVING or GROUP BY, and you don't specify the error ("I get failures" is not an actionable error message) it is near impossible to offer suggestions.  I would suggest that instead of the format 'SELECT owner.table.column FROM owner.table WHERE owner.table.column ...', you 'SELECT column FROM owner.table WHERE column ...''

Comment: Cause I get always a Failure for GROUP BY. The GROUP BY should sum "Value". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT LTRIM(MIN(SUBSTR(D.PNR, -5)), '0') AS Value,
       D.DOC, D.RE, D.ST
FROM POOLK.DATA d
WHERE D.DOC > 25000 AND 
      D.RE ='B9'
GROUP BY D.DOC, D.RE, D.ST;
```

I also added table aliases so the code is easier to write and to read.

The `INTO` is creating a table.  If you really want to do that then:

```
create table tvalue as
    SELECT LTRIM(MIN(SUBSTR(D.PNR, -5)), '0') AS Value,
           D.DOC, D.RE, D.ST
    FROM POOLK.DATA d
    WHERE D.DOC > 25000 AND 
          D.RE ='B9'
    GROUP BY D.DOC, D.RE, D.ST;
```

Comment: OP also still needs the `MIN` aggregation on calculated column, *Value* (which you add but do not mention).

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is about INTO? And why "Where"? Ist this the same as HAVING?

Comment: Using `INTO` runs the [make-table query](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b#bm2) in MS Access. The `HAVING` clause expressions in MS Access query should really be in the `WHERE` clause since no aggregate is used. The Query designer or you or previous programmer may have set it up that way.

Comment: Why do you use where instead of having?

Comment: @joshua1990 . . . Because filtering *before* aggregation is usually more efficient than filtering *after* aggregation.

Comment: How could a declare "LTRIM(MIN(SUBSTR(D.PNR, -5)), '0') AS Value," as a number? For now it displays as text.

Comment: You would use `TO_NUMBER()` somewhere in the expression.